# Trying to launch my node.js program with npm but nothing happens

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I am trying to make this slack bot run : https://github.com/lmammino/norrisbot

I am not very skilled with npm and node yet, but I follow his instructions and try to run the bot with the help of the `npm start` command.

Here's the output I get :

```
F:\norrisbot>npm start

> norrisbot@1.0.5 start F:\norrisbot
> node bin/bot.js


F:\norrisbot>
```

No error, but nothing happens either in the console or the slack general channel...

By the way I set up my `BOT_API_KEY` variable correctly (with the `token.js` method)

Comment: what happens if you run "node bin/bot.js"

Comment: @nycynik The same result, something _seems_ to be starting to run then I get back to console input (but without the 2 lines of details showing)

Answer (score 1):

By your command prompt it's clear you're running in Windows. The operations for running Node properly in Windows are different in several ways from Mac/Linux, and a LOT (most?) of developers don't address these because they're on Mac/Linux themselves. Path formats, file locations, how you expose environment variables, and all sorts of things are different in Win.

Try hand-editing bin/bot.js in your locally cloned copy of the repo. Find this line at the end of the file:

```
norrisbot.run();
```

Change it to read as follows:

```
console.log('Running Norris Bot');
norrisbot.run();
console.log('Ran Norris Bot');
```

I bet you will find that either NEITHER of these lines gets printed, or only one does.

If NEITHER line gets printed, the issue is with the `npm` command improperly formatting the path to the executable script for Windows users. In that case, try running it as (make sure NodeJS is in your PATH):

```
 node bin/bot.js
```

If only the FIRST line gets printed, there is almost certainly a bug elsewhere in the module itself. I didn't evaluate all of its code, and I'm not on Windows myself at the moment - I just use it often enough to be aware of its differences. But either way it will get you started on finding the issue, and if it's truly a bug, you can pursue the bug report I see you've already filed in Github.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your detailed answer! I added the debug code and see that the 2 lines are printed...

Comment: any idea what the problem could be with this output? I get the line `Ran Norris Bot`